# How to preserve spaces in Bash "for loop" expression

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have function that print lines with spaces and need to loop through the line with a for..in loop. How do I preserve the spaces and not tokenize based on them.

```
function getTwoThings
{
    echo "A B C"
    echo "X Y Z"
}

for L in `getTwoThings`
do
    echo $L
done

for L in "`getTwoThings`"
do
    echo $L
done
```

Produces either six things or one thing.

```
A
B
C
X
Y
Z

A B C X Y Z
```

How do I get it to produce two things?

Comment: [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read it like this using *process substitution*:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
   echo "$line"
done < <(getTwoThings)
```

**Output:**

```
A B C
X Y Z
```

Comment: Awesome, prefect answer.